# How do we use net.liftweb.http.js.JsCmds.Script object in lift?

Tags: javascript, templates, scala, rendering, lift

I am porting a legacy system from rails into lift. It has a lot of hard-coded concatenated javascript that I would like to render into html pages.

According to [this conversation](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/liftweb/V4mjRNJWZJ0) here, we can use net.liftweb.http.js.JsCmds.Script object this way:

```
Script("""
var x = "Here's my JavaScript & it looks good";
""")
```

However, I got this compiler message:

```
error: type mismatch;
[INFO]  found   : java.lang.String
[INFO]  required: net.liftweb.http.js.JsCmd
```

What is the correct way to use `net.liftweb.http.js.JsCmds.Script`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, the conversation is clearly wrong.

The `apply` method for `net.liftweb.http.js.JsCmds.Script` takes a JsCmd as a parameter - that's the source of your compiler error.

Now for that specific case, you could fix it to something like this:

```
Script(JsCrVar("x", new Str("Here's my JavaScript & it looks good")))
```

(Str is `net.liftweb.http.js.JE.Str`)

Comment: Thank you. I also got the other one running with "Script(new Run(javascript))".

Answer (score 1):

As Donald stated the JsCmds.Script() method takes a JsCmd as a parameter.
So you could write direct JS statements using JsRaw.

ex.

```
Script(JsRaw("""var x = "Here's my JavaScript & it looks good";"""))
```

Here's the discussion about this topic:: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/liftweb/1roPxxHIFJk/discussion